# How to make http(80) and https(443) work on different ports say 8000 for http and 4443 for https

Tags: nginx

How to make http(80) and https(443) work on different ports say 8000 for http and 4443 for https

Basically my requirement is to make request come on port 8000 instead of usual port http 80 and https redirection should happen(gets redirected) to port say 4443 instead regular https port 443.

Is above scenario possible or not.

If yes what changes do i need to make in nginx default.conf file to work.

Usual default.conf file of nginx web server

```
server {


   if ($host = example.co.uk) {
        return 301 https://example.co.uk$request_uri;
    }


   server_name example.co.uk;
    listen 80;
    return 404;
}

server {

    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name example.co.uk;



    ssl_certificate           /etc/nginx/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key       /etc/nginx/privkey.pem;
    ssl_buffer_size 8k;

    ssl_dhparam /etc/ssl/certs/dhparam-2048.pem;

#    listen ssl on;
    ssl_session_cache  builtin:1000  shared:SSL:10m;
    ssl_protocols  TLSv1.3 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

############################################################################################
    ssl_ciphers ECDH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+3DES:!ADH:!AECDH:!MD5;
    ssl_ecdh_curve secp384r1;
    ssl_session_tickets off;

    # OCSP stapling
    ssl_stapling on;
    ssl_stapling_verify on;
    

##########################################################################################

    access_log            /var/log/nginx/jenkins.access.log;

    location / {

      proxy_set_header        Host $host;
      proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

      #####################################
      
#      proxy_buffers 8 8k;
#      proxy_buffer_size 8k;

      proxy_buffering         on;
      proxy_buffer_size       128k;
      proxy_buffers           4 256k;
      proxy_busy_buffers_size 256k;
      
      #####################################

      # Fix the “It appears that your reverse proxy set up is broken" error.
      proxy_pass          http://example:8080;
      #proxy_read_timeout  90;
      
      proxy_connect_timeout 600;
      proxy_send_timeout 600;
      proxy_read_timeout 600;
      send_timeout 600;

      proxy_redirect      http://example:8080 https://example:8080;
    }
  }
```

Custom default.conf of nginx i tried to make it work with no success as of now

```
server {

   if ($host = example.co.uk:8000) {
        return 301 https://example.co.uk:4443$request_uri;
    }


   server_name example.co.uk;
    listen 8000;
    return 404;
}

server {

    listen 4443 ssl;
    server_name example.co.uk;



    ssl_certificate           /etc/nginx/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key       /etc/nginx/privkey.pem;
    ssl_buffer_size 8k;

    ssl_dhparam /etc/ssl/certs/dhparam-2048.pem;

#    listen ssl on;
    ssl_session_cache  builtin:1000  shared:SSL:10m;
    ssl_protocols  TLSv1.3 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

############################################################################################
    ssl_ciphers ECDH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+3DES:!ADH:!AECDH:!MD5;
    ssl_ecdh_curve secp384r1;
    ssl_session_tickets off;

    # OCSP stapling
    ssl_stapling on;
    ssl_stapling_verify on;
    

##########################################################################################

    access_log            /var/log/nginx/jenkins.access.log;

    location / {

      proxy_set_header        Host $host;
      proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

      #####################################
      
#      proxy_buffers 8 8k;
#      proxy_buffer_size 8k;

      proxy_buffering         on;
      proxy_buffer_size       128k;
      proxy_buffers           4 256k;
      proxy_busy_buffers_size 256k;
      
      #####################################

      # Fix the “It appears that your reverse proxy set up is broken" error.
      proxy_pass          http://example:8080;
      #proxy_read_timeout  90;
      
      proxy_connect_timeout 600;
      proxy_send_timeout 600;
      proxy_read_timeout 600;
      send_timeout 600;

      proxy_redirect      http://example:8080 https://example:8080;
    }
  }
```

Could someone please help me out over here with this scenario.

Thanks & Regards

Answer (score 0):

It's possible, I just did it in my server. But I never change the default.conf file.
I made a file in `/etc/nginx/sites-available` and then made a shortcut to `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled` using the `ln -s firstDirectory secondDirectory`.
I first handled the http request to port 8000.
Then I used certbot to make ssl, and changed 443s in my file to 4433.
Honestly your code is a bit confusing and I have never worked with default.conf file before. But here is my file, hope you could figure it out:
https://gist.github.com/ParsaArvanehPA/3638c8729f6021c0ca8efc0df076fabb